# Provision an Office365 Group and disable shared email address

Tags: office-365-groups

I'm wondering about a couple things with Office365 Groups:

1. Is it possible to provision a group and to disable certain services, e.g. the shared inbox and calendar? (the reason being is to not conflict with existing distribution lists)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. Office 365 Groups are a take it or leave it object.

Comment: Thanks, it would be interesting to know if they have plans on expanding the configurability of groups in the future.

Comment: @Ushka why not just create a modern SharePoint site?